# How to get Context for logging when using APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent in aws-lambda

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

My project is written in spring-cloud-function and deployed in aws-lambda. I have a requirement wherein I am supposed to log the events.

A little search told me to use

`com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context` for logging by doing this:

```
context.getLogger().log("log event here");
```

I have a spring cloud function which receives APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent as the input and APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent as the output parameter

I searched again and found to get the context, this can be wrapped with `org.springframework.messaging.Message`

so I wrote the function like this:

```
public Function<Message<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent>, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> saveEmployee(){
return request -> {
            Context context = request.getHeaders().get("aws-context", Context.class);
context.getLogger().log("employee save request---: " + request);
    //do something
```

However the context evaluates to null and I get NullPointerException

Can someone point to what might be going wrong? or how to fetch context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any pointers anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the following handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the RequestHandler class and oveeride handleRequest method. The context parameter can be used to enter logs for cloudwatch.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Function implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>  {

@Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(final APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, final Context context) {

LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
logger.log(event);
```